# Oh ye beloved bejeweled

Tags: game, scala

Before @bazola asked [his recent question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74221/board-evaluator-for-bejeweled-clone), we chatted about it for a bit. I figured that I could try implementing something similar myself.

As I've heard that Scala [has all the advantages of Java, but fewer of the disadvantages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=all%20the%20advantages%20of%20java&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest), I'd figured that I could try it.

I have implemented checking for board matches, removing them, and refilling the board.

I have not yet implemented any user interaction (and I'm not asking for any help in doing so either). The program simply generates a bejeweled board, then repeatedly removes all the matches and refills the board until no matches remain. In a real bejeweled game, this could be used to set up an initial board.

In the code, I have added output for each step and a pause (by reading input) just so that it's possible to see the progress.

- Bejeweled.scala: Main program, creates the board and performs the loop of clearing and refilling
- MatchMap.scala: The game board
- MatchTile.scala: One tile on the game board

## Code

**Bejeweled.scala:**

```
import java.util.Scanner

object Bejeweled {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val map = new MatchMap(8, 8, 3);
      val sc = new Scanner(System.in)
      var cleared = false
      do {
        cleared = false
        map.print
        map.matchCheck
        map.print
        println("CLEAR")
        sc.nextLine
        while (map.clear) {
          map.print
          println("CLEAR 2")
          sc.nextLine
          cleared = true
        }
      }
      while (cleared)

      map print
    }

}
```

**MatchMap.scala:**

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import java.util.{List, Random, LinkedList, ArrayList}

class MatchMap(xsize: Integer, ysize: Integer, matchCount: Integer) {

    def width = xsize
    def height = ysize
    def matches = matchCount
    def uniqueTiles = 5

    val grid = Array.ofDim[MatchTile](ysize, xsize)
    val random = new Random()
    init()
    generate()

    def init() {
      for (x <- 0 to xsize - 1) {
        for (y <- 0 to ysize - 1) {
            grid(y)(x) = new MatchTile(this, x, y)
        }
      }
    }

    def generate() {
      for (x <- 0 to xsize - 1) {
        for (y <- 0 to ysize - 1) {
            grid(y)(x) random
        }
      }
    }

    def clear(): Boolean = {
      grid.reverse.count(row => row.count(tile => tile fall) > 0) > 0
    }

    def removeValues(row: Array[MatchTile], index: Integer, count: Integer) {
      for (i <- 1 to count) {
        row(index - i).clear
      }
    }

    def checkArray(row: Array[MatchTile]): Boolean = {
      var checkFor = row(0).value
      var count = 0

      for (i <- 0 to row.length - 1) {
        val curr = Math.abs(row(i).value)
        if (checkFor != curr) {
            if (count >= matches) {
                removeValues(row, i, count)
            }
            checkFor = curr
            count = 1
        }
        else {
            count = count + 1
        }
      }
      false
    }

    def matchCheck(): Boolean = {
      grid.reverse.foreach(row => checkArray(row))
      grid.transpose.foreach(row => checkArray(row))
      false
    }

    def print() {
      println("-------")
      println(this)
    }

    override def toString(): String = {
      val str = new StringBuilder
      grid.foreach(row => {
        row.foreach(col => {
          val ch = col;
          str append col
        })
        str.append("\n")
      })
      str toString
    }
}
```

**MatchTile.scala:**

```
class MatchTile(map: MatchMap, posX: Integer, posY: Integer) {

  def x = posX
  def y = posY
  def m = map
  var value: Integer = 0

  def clear() {
    value = -Math.abs(value)
  }

  def isTopRow: Boolean = y == 0

  def fall: Boolean = {
    if (value < 0) {
      if (isTopRow) {
        random
        return false
      }
      else {
        value = m.grid(y - 1)(x).value
        m.grid(y - 1)(x).clear
      }
      return true
    }
    false
  }

  def random {
    value = m.random.nextInt(m.uniqueTiles) + 1
  }

  override def toString(): String = {
    if (value < 0) {
      '_' toString()
    }
    else {
      value toString()
    }
  }


}
```

## Example:

Initially generated board

```
15413551
42524142
21255554
43422422
35311111
51543552
15333311
53134424
```

Find matches:

```
15413551
42524142
212____4
43422422
35311111
51543552
15____11
53134424
```

Apply gravity and refill from top:

```
15554541
42413552
21524144
432___22
35422411
51311152
15543511
53134424
```

Another gravity + refill:

```
15554341
42454552
21513544
43224122
35422411
51311152
15543511
53134424
```

Find matches, clear:

```
1___4341
42454552
21513544
43224122
35422411
513___52
15543511
53134424
```

Gravity + refill:

```
15521541
424_4352
21554544
43213522
35424111
51322452
15543511
53134424
```

Again:

```
15541541
42424352
21554544
43213522
35424111
51322452
15543511
53134424
```

No more matches!

## Questions

As I come from a Java background, I guess there are a ton of Scala tricks that I could apply here.

Even though this is the first time using the language for "real", I feel that I grasp the basic concepts of the language. I find the documentation of it very confusing though, but that's another story.

Feel free to comment about anything you'd like, but I'm mostly interested in what Scala things I can use to make this code more Scala-like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Notes**

1. Although I was tempted to seek a purely functional solution to the Bejeweled problem, I realized that in doing so, your code would become mostly unrecognizable (removing mutability would change the underlying class structures and algorithms) and you wouldn't gain much benefit from the refactoring. So I kept the logic of your program the same and just refactored for conciseness and idiomatic Scala style.
2. In the methods `init` and `generate` you create a range inclusively but subtract `1` from the upper limit of the range. Instead of subtracting `1` just build your range exclusively like so:

   ```
   // do this
   for (x <- 0 until width) 
   // not this
   for (x <- 0 to width - 1)
   ```
3. In your original code there were a couple of places where you would define a function as an `Integer` or `Boolean`, instead just assign the value or expression result to a `val`.

   ```
   // do this
   val width = xsize
   // not this
   def width = xsize
   ```
4. In Scala you generally never have to use a return statement. In your original code you use them in the `MatchTile` method `fall`. I've reformatted that method such that the return statements are no longer necessary.
5. As far as I could tell the methods `matchCheck` and `checkArray` don't need to return a value (originally you return a `Boolean` from them). I've refactored the code changing the return type to `Unit`, the Scala equivalent to `void`.
6. I refactored the `toString` method in `MatchMap` to make it considerably more concise by utilizing `mkString`. Also instead of hard-coding a separator (`"--------"`) you could make the separator dependent on `width` (`"-" * width`). Also, with the changes to `toString` I was able to remove the `print()` method that you had.
7. Removed boilerplate class field initialization by converting `MatchMap` to a `case class` and by prefixing `val` to the parameters of `MatchTile`. Parameters of a case class automatically become class fields. You can tell the compiler that the parameters of a (non case) class are supposed to be fields by prefixing them with `val`. Examples:

   ```
   // do this
   case class MatchMap(w: Int, h: Int) { ... }
   // or this
   class MatchMap(val w: Int, val h: Int) { ... }
   // not this
   class MatchMap(w: Int, h: Int) {
     val width = w
     val height = h
   }
   ```
8. I made the initialization of `grid` in MatchMap more concise by using the `tabulate` method, allowing me to remove `generate()` and `init()`.
9. Note that in #7 the integer parameters are declared with `Int` and not `Integer`.
10. There were one or two places where a semicolon slipped in where they weren't needed.

**CODE**

```
 case class MatchMap(width: Int, height: Int, matches: Int) {
    val uniqueTiles = 5
    val rand = new Random()
    val grid =
      Vector.tabulate(height, width)((y, x) =>
        new MatchTile(this, y, x, rand.nextInt(uniqueTiles) + 1))

    def clear(): Boolean =
      grid.reverse.count(row =>
        row.count(tile =>
          tile.fall) > 0) > 0

    def removeValues(row: Vector[MatchTile], index: Int, count: Int): Unit =
      for (i <- 1 to count)
        row(index - i).clear()

    def checkArray(row: Vector[MatchTile]): Unit = {
      var checkFor = row(0).value
      var count = 0

      for (i <- 0 until row.length) {
        val curr = Math.abs(row(i).value)
        if (checkFor != curr) {
          if (count >= matches)
            removeValues(row, i, count)
          checkFor = curr
          count = 1
        }
        else
          count = count + 1
      }
    }

    def matchCheck(): Unit = {
      grid.reverse.foreach(row => checkArray(row))
      grid.transpose.foreach(row => checkArray(row))
    }

    override def toString = {
      ("-" * width) + "\n" +
      (grid map (row => row.mkString)).mkString("\n")
    }
  }

  class MatchTile(val m: MatchMap, val x: Int, val y: Int, var value: Int) {

    def clear() =
      value = -Math.abs(value)

    val isTopRow = y == 0

    def fall: Boolean = value match {
      case _ if value < 0 =>
        if (isTopRow) {
          random()
          false
        } else {
          value = m.grid(y - 1)(x).value
          m.grid(y - 1)(x).clear()
          true
        }
      case _ =>
        false
    }

    def random() =
      value = m.rand.nextInt(m.uniqueTiles) + 1

    override def toString =
      if (value < 0) "_"
      else s"$value"
  }
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I don't quite understand all the Scala magic yet, but your answer will definitely help me understand it!